# How to reload iframe dynamically when the source link is updated

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs

it's required to dynamically update the source for an iframe. And when the link is updated, iframe should reload itself.
Google doesn't provide me with the working solution.
Currently i'm trying to remove iframe from the parent panel if it's inactive, and add it once again when the tab is active.

```
var myIFrame = new Ext.BoxComponent({
 autoEl:{
    id:'myIFramePanel',
    tag:'iframe',
    border:false,
    src:'myConfiguration/getMyConfigurationPage'
 }
});

myConfigurationPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
id:'myConfigurationPanel',
layout:'fit',
frame:true,
defaults:{autoScroll:true},

listeners:{
    deactivate:function (panel) {
        console.info('-------DEACTIVATE TAB');
        panel.removeAll();
    },
    activate:function (panel) {
        console.info('-------ACTIVATE TAB');
        panel.add(myIFrame);
        var myIFramePanel = document.getElementById('myIFramePanel'); // always null
        if (myIFramePanel) {
            var updater = Ext.get(myIFramePanel).getUpdateManager();
            updater.update('newLink');
        }
    }
},

initComponent:function () {
    myConfigurationPanel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the `src` property of an iframe will update it.

Furthermore, you must wait for your `BoxComponent` to have been rendered for the iframe to be available in the DOM. Then only, you can access it with `getElementById` or equivalent.

What you should do is add a method to change the iframe src if it is already rendered, or change the `src` of the element if it is not rendered yet. This way, you can call this method whenever you need.

```
var myIFrame = new Ext.BoxComponent({
    autoEl:{
        id:'myIFramePanel',
        tag:'iframe',
        border:false,
        src:'myConfiguration/getMyConfigurationPage'
    }

    ,setSrc: function(src) {
        if (this.rendered) {
            // equivalent to:
            // document.getElementById('myIFramePanel').src = src;
            Ext.get('myIFramePanel').set({
                src: src
            });
        } else {
            this.autoEl.src = src;
        }
    }
});
```

Then, later:

```
// will always work
myIFrame.setSrc(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't help - the src link is updated, but when I activate the tab with iframe it doesn't lead to load info from the source.

Comment: I've noticed that if I put a breakpoint after container.doLayout(), when the iframe is represented and everything is ok. But in runtime the panel is empty...                                                  console.info('-----------------ADD A NEW IFRAME');
this.add({
    xtype:'box',
    autoEl:{
        id:"myIFramePanel",
        tag:'iframe',
        frameborder:0,
        src:'myConfiguration/getMyConfigurationPage'
    }
    });
this.doLayout();
console.info('-----------------A NEW IFRAME ADDED');